# Inserting clob-data into different table-columns

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I have a table named 'uploaded_files' that stores *csv.files which are uploaded via dropzone (https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-dropzone) by a user in my webapplication. The content of that files is stored in a tablecolumn of datatype blob.

To insert the file-content I am using a package called 'csv_util_pkg' (https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils). I managed to convert the blob-datatype to clob-datatype and store the clob-data into another table called x_dump. [X_Dump Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9TRV.jpg) As you can see in the picture the clob_values are separated and stored in 'c001' and 'c002'. This is done by a function of the csv_util_pkg.

Now I want to take those two values and store them in a table called 'fahrzeug' but this doesn't work and I really don't know why. I am getting the following error code

```
ORA-01400: Einfügen von NULL in ("RESSOURCE_U"."FAHRZEUG"."VNUMMER") nicht möglich
ORA-06512: in Zeile 14
01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert NULL into previously listed objects.
*Action:   These objects cannot accept NULL values.
```

And here is my code:

```
DECLARE
    file_content   NUMBER (10);
    l_clob         CLOB;
BEGIN
    SELECT TO_CLOB (
               UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (FILE_BLOB, 2000)))
      INTO l_clob
      FROM UPLOADED_FILES
     WHERE UPLOADED_FILES.FILENAME LIKE 'A_%_Fahrzeug.csv';

    INSERT INTO X_DUMP (CLOB_VALUE, DUMP_ID)
         VALUES (l_clob, 1);

    INSERT INTO fahrzeug (vnummer, baureihe)
        SELECT c001, c002
          FROM x_dump d, TABLE (csv_util_pkg.clob_to_csv (d.clob_value, ';'));

    COMMIT;
END;
```

vnummer is the primary key of my table 'fahrzeug' and thus we can not insert null. But I don't understand that because c001 and c002 contain values so it can't be null..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug or output the c001 during runtime? Try this:

```
for tmp IN (select c001 from x_dump d, table(csv_util_pkg.clob_to_csv(d.clob_value, ';')))
LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('vnummer: ' || tmp.c001);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately your command is not compiling and I am getting an error code. But what I found out is the following:

The insert statement on 'fahrzeug' is generally working because it inserts the first row of my x_dump table (c001 is not null there). It then comes to a problem when oracle tries to insert the second line of my table because 'c001' is NULL in the second row.

Comment: That's a little bit confusing for me because of two facts:

1) I only have one Insert-statement on the x_dump table so why does x_dump contain two rows? It only should contain one row because there is no loop or something else.
2) Similar problem I don't understand when Oracle tries to insert into 'fahrzeug'. It is only one command and there is no loop so there should be only one insert into fahrzeug, so why does oracle want to insert two times?

Comment: I modified the output-snippet. I don't know what is in your x_dump-Table or table(csv..) but you're not joining them. Is this correct?

Comment: create table x_dump
(clob_value clob,
 dump_date date default sysdate,
 dump_id number);

This is how my table is created. And you are correct, I don't join the table.